# ASP.NET Trigger c# event from JavaScript button click

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, event-handling

I have this code in an ASP.NET Page

```
function ShowPopup() {
    $("#GridView2").dialog({
        title: "GridView2",
        width: 1200,
        buttons: {
            Ok: function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
            ,
            Export: function funcXport() {
                //EVENT HERE?
            }
        },
        modal: true
    });
```

which is a popup with a gridview and there are 2 buttons on it.

I want the "Ok" button to actually close the Grid but I'd like the "Export" button to trigger an event (I suppose) so I can write a C# code that exports the GridView to an EXCEL file.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could do it with a little trick:

Define a non-visble button and click it:

```
<asp:Button ID="ButtonID" runat="server" OnClick="DoExport" style="visibility: hidden; display: none;" />
```

Then:

```
 Export: function funcXport() {
                    $("#<%=ButtonID.ClientID%>").Click();
                }
```

Or use `ClientIDMode=Static` on the button and `$("#ButtonID").click();`

Comment: So i went like <asp:Button ID="ButtonID" runat="server" OnClick="export" style="visibility: hidden; display: none;" /> /////Export: function funcXport() {                    $("#<%=ButtonID.ClientID%>").Click();} ///////// and on C# /////   protected void export(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    } /////////// with a breakpoint just to see if i hit it, but nothing happens :(  , What i find out is that the hidden button is outside the <asp:GridView id="GridView2"> Do you think that's what's wrong?

Comment: <asp:Button runat="server" ID="MyButton" OnClick="MyButton_Click" Text="Test" style="visibility: hidden; display: none;" ClientIDMode="Static" />

Comment: $("#MyButton").click();

Comment: thanks so much for trying man , but for some reason it's not working im like

Comment: <asp:Button ID="ButtonID" runat="server" OnClick="export" ClientIDMode="Static" style="visibility: hidden; display: none;" />

Comment: buttons: {
                            Ok: function () {
                                $(this).dialog('close');
                            }
                            ,
                            Export: function () {
                                $("#ButtonID").Click();
                            }

Comment: the event is not getting triggered :S

Comment: Clientside its "click" not "Click", $("#ButtonID").click();

Comment: sadly no :( thanks for trying i might be mistaken somewhere else in the code, but everything works fine :s